# Debian 9 - Permitir IP especifica para conectarse a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, debian, debian-9

He intentado solucionar el problema con IPTables, pero la verdad no resulta ser muy claro para mi.

```
.
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.120 -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
.
```

No comprendo.

Ejecuto el código y funciona, pero de ahí. No sé que hizo o qué cambios realizó.

Y pues como tal, mi finalidad es registrar las IP que pueden tener acceso a **Mongo** o *su puerto*, y no permitir el acceso a **Mongo** con otras IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí una respuesta que hallé

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT #Aceptar todas las conexiones ENTRANTES de cualquier IP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT #Aceptar todas las conexiones SALIENTES de cualquier IP
iptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.2.153 --destination 192.168.2.180 --protocol tcp --dport 27016 --jump ACCEPT #ACEPTAR UNICAMENTE LA CONEXION DE 192.168.2.153 A LA IP 192.168.2.180(MAQUINA HOST), Y UNICAMENTE AL PUERTO 27016 (MONGODB)
iptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.2.153 --destination 192.168.2.180 --protocol tcp --dport 22 --jump ACCEPT #ACEPTAR UNICAMENTE LA CONEXION DE 192.168.2.153 A LA IP 192.168.2.180(MAQUINA HOST), Y UNICAMENTE AL PUERTO 22 (CONEXIONES SSH)
iptables -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.2.180 --jump ACCEPT #Aceptar todas las conexiones salientes únicamente de la IP 192.168.2.180(MAQUINA HOST)
iptables -A INPUT --destination 192.168.2.180 --jump DROP #NEGAR | PROHIBIR acceso de entrada a cualquier IP no listada, las conexiones entrantes a 192.168.2.180(MAQUINA HOST)
.
```

Con el codigo anterior se permitirá la conexion entrante de la ip **192.168.2.153** a la ip del **servidor 192.168.2.180** sólo si los puertos son **22 (Conexión SSH)** o (*en este caso*) **27016**; conexiones a otros puertos serán rechazadas.

Cualquier conexion saliente de la ip del **servidor 192.168.2.180** será permitida, pero cualquier conexion a la ip del **servidor 192.168.2.180** que NO esté listada será rechazada.

### **Plus** - Guardar la configuración, ejecutarla y hacerla persistente

Para guardar esta configuración de iptables, asegúrate de ser Administrador o SuperUsuario:

```
su
```

Luego crea un archivo .sh con nano. Guárdalo en alguna carpeta y mantén en mente dónde lo guardaste.

```
cd /etc/ #Ir a la carpeta etc, eso es decisión de ustedes
mkdir prueba-iptables #Crear un carpeta llamada prueba-iptables
cd prueba-iptables #Abrir la carpeta prueba-iptables (Recordar que estamos actualmente en /etc/)
nano reglas.sh #Abrir el editor nano, para crear el archivo reglas.sh
.
```

Veremos algo como ésto

[image: macOS SSH to Debian 9 - Nano Editor]

Escriben la configuración de iptables anteriormente mencionada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberá verse *más o menos así*

Luego, presionar **CTRL + o**, y **ENTER**

Con ello tendrán "reglas.sh" guardado en /etc/prueba-iptables/

Presiona **CTRL X** para salir del editor nano

Escribir en la terminal (consola):

```
/etc/prueba-iptables/reglas.sh  #Esto ejecuta el codigo en reglas.sh
.
```

Si todo está bien, no deberá salir nada.

Luego, escribir:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 #Esto guarda la configuración actual (temporal) de iptables en rules.v4 para después hacerlas permanentes
.
```

Luego, escribir:

```
dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent #Saldrá un cuadro grande en pantalla completa, aceptar IPv4, IPv6 según necesites, si eres nuevo. Sólo acepta (yes).
reboot #Reiniciar la máquina fisica del servidor !!!Cuidado con esto, preguntar primero si está permitido reiniciar la máquina en su empresa o negocio!!!
.
```

Y listo, con ello ya tendrán guardada la configuración de iptables y de forma persistente.

Para verificar que las reglas estén en ejecución ingresa en la consola:

```
iptables -L
```

Ten en cuenta que demorará en cargar las reglas.

Para restablecer las reglas a su estado original (Permitir todas las ip):

```
iptables -F #Limpiar las reglas de iptables
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 #Guardar la nueva configuracion de iptables
dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent #Reconfigurar
reboot #Reinciar la maquina host.
.
```

Y listo :))

Espero les sea de utilidad